# Create task definition with port mapping UDP port on AWS cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-ecs

On the AWS cloudformation I have to create a task definition for ECS cluster. How can I specify UDP and TCP port on the Portmapping? I tried like this, but not working

```
"PortMappings": [
{
      "ContainerPort": 8500,
      "HostPort": 8500,
      "Protocol": "TCP"
},
{
      "ContainerPort": 8500,
      "HostPort": 8500,
      "Protocol": "UDP"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

[From the ECS Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide//task_definition_parameters.html):

> The protocol used for the port mapping. Valid values are **tcp** and **udp**.
>   The default is tcp.

You should try to write the protocol in lower case.